# Error: Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.PersonAccount'

Tags: visualforce, person-accounts

I am trying to append Person Account email ID with the Eloqua profiler login URL. And I am getting an error after pasting the below code in visualforce page.

Error: Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.PersonAccount'

**Please Note:** I have dummied the Eloqua **siteID** in the below code.

**Code:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

<head></head>

<body>

<iframe src="https://login.eloqua.com/autoLogin?LoginPrefix=<siteID>&Url=/apps/profiler/index.aspx?emailAddress={!PersonAccount.email}" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</body>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the keyword `Account` when referencing standard objects fields on the page:

```
{!Account.PersonEmail}
```

Here you will find more infos about how to reference the fields using a standard controller: [Building Visualforce Pages Using Standard Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller#Referencing_a_Single_Record)